# How to move a circle inside a svg in the firefox browser with offsetX and offsetY?

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-browser

I have written some code in javascript, which allows the user to manipulate a circle inside a svg.

I provided some code below. Here you can move a circle. On Chrome as well as Egde it works perfectly. On Firefox it does not work. When I move the circle, it teleports nearly every second pixel to the top left corner. I have the version 67.0.4.

The following code is using a svg by the id "svg" from inside a html file.

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/dodo978/pen/BgvzYv?editors=0010)

```
const svg = document.getElementById('svg');
const circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
circle.setAttribute("cx", "100px");
circle.setAttribute("cy", "100px");
circle.setAttribute("r", "50px");
circle.setAttribute("fill", "blue");
svg.appendChild(circle);

let pressed = false;

svg.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
  pressed = true;
});

svg.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  if (pressed) {
    circle.setAttribute("cx", e.offsetX);
    circle.setAttribute("cy", e.offsetY);
  }
});

svg.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
  pressed = false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

USE `clientX` and `clientY` . I think `offsetX` and `offsetY` are deprecated in Firefox

```js
const svg = document.getElementById('svg');
const circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
circle.setAttribute("cx", "100px");
circle.setAttribute("cy", "100px");
circle.setAttribute("r", "50px");
circle.setAttribute("fill", "blue");
svg.appendChild(circle);

let pressed = false;

svg.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
  pressed = true;
});

svg.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  if (pressed) {
    circle.setAttribute("cx", e.clientX);
    circle.setAttribute("cy", e.clientY);
  }
});

svg.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
  pressed = false;
});
```

```css
svg {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="300" height="200"><svg>
```